# Using selected vector element as an operator

Tags: r, r-markdown

If I define a vector as:

```
vec <- c("for", "paste")
```

Is there any way to apply a selection on this vector and use the result as an operator? I have tried like this:

```
vec[1](i, 0:10, print("Hello"))
```

but the result is an error:

> Error: attempt to apply non-function

Comment: If I recall some jank like this could work `eval(parse(text=paste0(vec[1],’(i, 0:10, print("Hello"))’)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first element in 'vec' i.e. `for` is a Primitive function, so, we can append `.Primitive`

```
.Primitive(vec[1])(i, 0:10, print("Hello"))
```

-output

```
#[1] "Hello"
#[1] "Hello"
#[1] "Hello"
#[1] "Hello"
#[1] "Hello"
#[1] "Hello"
#[1] "Hello"
#[1] "Hello"
#[1] "Hello"
#[1] "Hello"
#[1] "Hello"
```

while `paste` is not Primitive.  Not clear from the OP's post about the expected output for second element.  With `match.fun`, we can use

```
match.fun(vec[2])(rep("Hello", 10), collapse=", ")
#[1] "Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello"
```

assuming that OP' wants to `paste` 10 "Hello" into a single string

Comment: @tacoman The OP's example code was using `for` and it is Primitive, while `paste` is not Primitive

Comment: @tacoman Not sure what the expected output for `paste` in OP's example

Answer (score 2):

How about?

```
vec <- c("for", "paste")
do.call(vec[[1]], list(as.symbol('i'), 0:10, substitute(print('Hello'))))
```